# how to add android and ios platform in ionic cli 3.3.0

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I update ionic and trying to add android and ios platform but i could not add it. it shows me following message in console.

```
js20@js20:~/Desktop/project$ ionic platform add android
The platform command has been renamed. To find out more, run:

ionic cordova platform --help
```

My ionic version

```
js20@js20:~/Desktop/project$ ionic -v
3.3.0
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

we can simply use following commands

```
ionic cordova platform add android
or
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

to run

```
ionic cordova run android --device
ionic cordova run ios
ionic cordova run ios --prod --release
```

to build

```
ionic cordova build android
ionic cordova build ios
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
```

Comment: What about for ios? Is it "ionic cordova build ios"?

Comment: @SachinHR please check the answer. it is updated now.

Answer (score 0):

If are you facing any problem while adding and removing platform.

Recently I am unable to remove and add platform using

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

It is not get add in project.

Then finally i add platform using cordova commands

```
cordova platform add android
```